# Can I test Solr through a DropBox shared folders?

Tags: database, file, search, solr

I am new to using Solr and I am struggling with testing the search for the first time. I see in online tutorials people have many different means of testing their cores. Can I test a core on a DropBox shared folder? If so How?

This going to be a search engine for a website that will have articles blog posts and other references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropBox is an simple storage, not a place where you can execute something.
You need an environment, where you cat run the solr server. For example an linux server.

You can put your solr home and your solr binary into an dropbox folder in order to mount this folder to an server. Than you can execute/run the solr service at the machine, where the dropbox folder is mounted.