# Using Apache Solr with 'metadata' in Excel and files in DropBox

Tags: excel, search, web-applications, solr, full-text-search

First of all, apologies for what might seem like an 'amateur' scenario & question...

**Situation**

- I have many, many documents (100,000) that I need to users to be able to search and browse via a web application we are building
- This search functionality is just 1 of several other functions
- I currently have around a dozen excel spreadsheets that contain the 'metadata' (title, date, author, source, country etc.) or document information
- Each of the 100,000 'records' (or excel rows) has a unique identifier
- The actual files (majority PDF but some Word & Excel) are stored in Dropbox using the corresponding unique identifier as the file name

**Questions**

- Is Apache Solr the best tool to use in order to provide the search functionality?
- What is the best design to facilitate this (e.g. Files in AWS S3 etc.)?
- What is the best method to migrate from excel/Dropbox to the proposed Apache solr solution?

I very much appreciate any assistance as I have just been getting many different answers from paid consultants.

Regards
Mark

Comment: You can definitely use the apache solr. Need to check how to get the documents from the Dropbox...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451406/can-i-test-solr-through-a-dropbox-shared-folders

Comment: Thank you, appreciate you taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

Q: Is Apache Solr the best tool to use in order to provide the search functionality?

A: In my opinion, Solr is an awesome option for things like this.  However, as you've discovered, there's "some assembly required" (and that's putting it mildly)

Q: What is the best design to facilitate this (e.g. Files in AWS S3 etc.)?

A: If it were me, I'd use the filesystem.  I think it's the easiest to debug.

Also, if it were me, I'd export the Excel sheets to CSV, I think it's a bit easier to work with then.  However, Solr does include open source Tika filters, which do support Excel, but they won't treat your multiple-records as multiple-documents; Tika will make each Excel sheet into just one document each.

Q: What is the best method to migrate from excel/Dropbox to the proposed Apache solr solution?

A: I'm a fan of local filesystem.  Dropbox does let you mirror your Dropbox files on a local directory.  And as I said before, if you can get the Excel sheets exported to CSV, in some automated or "macro" way, I think it'd make your life easier too.  For example, Python can read and write CSV files and is a great tool for messaging data into its final form.

If you don't mind commercial solutions, you might consider Lucidworks Fusion; it does include a bunch of connectors, including a filesystem datasource connector.  Disclaimer: I happen to work for Lucid, but listing this suggestion last, before the "free" answers.  And I'd mention this anyway, even if I didn't work there.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Very much appreciate your comprehensive answer!